# how can i remove the path from zip file

Tags: java

I have a zip file that has a path. When I unzip the file and put it in my target folder, it then creates folders of the path.

```
public boolean doZip(String fileName, String zipfilename) {

    boolean zipStatus = true;

    try {
        String[] filesToZipP = new String[1];
        filesToZipP[0] = fileName;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        ZipOutputStream out =
            new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipfilename));

        out.setLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);

        for (int i = 0; i < filesToZipP.length; i++) {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filesToZipP[i]);
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filesToZipP[i]));

            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            out.closeEntry();
            in.close();
        }
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        zipStatus = false;

    }
    return zipStatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that i simply use my own path and the name of the file.

```
fis = new FileInputStream(dirList[i])
ZipEntry anEntry = new ZipEntry(rootName + "/" + dirList[i].name)
zos.putNextEntry(anEntry)
```

with rootName = "" if your zip file does not contain any folder.
Basically your path must be relative to the root of your zip file.
I hope you understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String name = new File(filesToZipP[i]).getName();
   out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
```